# How to get the full path to the Windows Explorer in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-explorer

Can I safely assume that Windows Explorer is always started from a Windows system directory? Also, is its process always named "explorer.exe"?

And if not, how to get its full file path?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention -- I need this to later find out the process ID of the Windows Explorer running in a given user session. Thus my search for its full path.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks everyone who contributed, and especially to sehe! After his post I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) that explains how to set up your own shell. I made a wild test by completely replacing explorer.exe with my own process and here's the result:
[image]
Here's the [full-size link](http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/fake_windows_explorer.jpg) if you it gets re-sized.

As you can see, I can technically replace explorer.exe with whatever process I may come up with. As you can also see in my screenshot Windows gives me a complete control over the *Shell* (the screenshot is my entire window.)

So the bottom line, the only way to get "explorer.exe" file path (or whatever Shell process is used) is to use those registry keys from the link I quoted above -- pretty much close to what sehe suggested, with just a few more checks to do, but it's a pretty straightforward stuff.

As for Sean Cline's suggestion, it would be a very elegant solution ONLY if we have the "stock" Windows Explorer running that comes with a tray window with that specific class name.

Comment: You may want to be a little more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. It may not be necessary to make any assumptions about the name or location of the shell depending on what you would like to do.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I need to know process ID of the Windows Explorer running in a given user session. Thus my search for its full path.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason for knowing the PID of the shell process, myself, but I've updated my answer. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: If you explain why you need the pid, maybe somebody can solve your actual problem. You cannot do much with explorer's pid. You should be using the appropriate shell APIs. There are terminal services scenarios where explorer is not the shell, and of course there are also cases where more than one copy of explorer is running.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I need PID of the Windows Explorer to determine if a specific process was started by a user or by the system. It is an altogether different discussion, but in a nutshell, I use child-parent process tree to determine this inheritance.

Comment: That is not a reliable test. The process may have been launched from, say, a command prompt, or by Notepad, or by a secondary Explorer. (What do you mean by "launched by the system" anyway?)

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, but where would command prompt come from? It would be run from the explorer. Although, if someone closes the cmd window it would "break the chain." So yes, this method of getting a descendancy is not very reliable.

Comment: Let's step back from the question to try to solve your problem. What is the actual problem? If you want to distinguish how a process was launched, why not pass it as a command line parameter? (Note that "launched by the system" is pretty vague. Explorer will launch programs from the Startup group; is that considered launched by the system?)

Answer (score 4):

It is probably safe to assume that explorer.exe is always in the %windir% or %SystemRoot% as it hasn't moved for years. But, if you are trying to invoke something via Explorer, chances are you want to use the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() function instead.

If you really do need the path, the easiest way to get it is probably with a call to [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() using FOLDERID_Windows as the first argument.

**Edit:**
Here is my stab at some code knowing that you are looking for the PID of the shell process:

```
DWORD trayPID;
HWND trayWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
GetWindowThreadProcessId(trayWnd, &trayPID);
```

It looks for the hWnd of the taskbar and finds the owning PID. You will likely need to add some error handling for the case that explorer is not running and that window does not exist - unlikely, but possible.

Comment: I was actually using GetWindowsDirectory() to get the system folder. But now after reading @sehe 's comment, I'm inclined to think that I need to get the Explorer's name from the shell (from the registry.)

Comment: Yes, +1 for unorthodox solution. Although still not a final answer, since as you pointed out the tray window may not exist.

Comment: Update: Posted a solution in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't safely assume that and none of this has to do with C++.

Also, you didn't show any code. Here goes:

The registry key for this is `Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

LONG GetStringRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, std::wstring &strValue, const std::wstring &strDefaultValue)
{
    strValue = strDefaultValue;
    WCHAR szBuffer[512];
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    ULONG nError;
    nError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        strValue = szBuffer;
    }
    return nError;
}

int main()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WinLogon", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    bool bExistsAndSuccess (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    bool bDoesNotExistsSpecifically (lRes == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    std::wstring shell;
    GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"Shell", shell, L"");
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the "Shell" registry entry has a couple caveats. It does not include the full path, just the executable name. Also, any user that has installed a replacement to the regular shell will have a different value for this key, although this is very rare.

Comment: @sehe Thanks for your input. I did not know about such registry key. So, since there's no full path there, can I assume that the file is located in the system folder that I can get from GetWindowsDirectory() call?

Comment: I updated my original question with a solution based on your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: @SeanCline Oh that surprises me. I had no windows machine to test the code on. I just wrote it in a text editor. Also, the fact that you'd get a different executable in case the user has a different shell, was entirely the purpose! Why not 'hardcode' %WINDIR%\explorer.exe, otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both.  Windows Explorer is always located at `%WINDIR%\Explorer.exe`.

Comment: Really?! I'm not convinced. Can you quote a source?

Comment: Yes, agreed. Although, since I did not phrase my original question correctly by referring to a Shell process as explorer.exe, he might be right specifically about the "stock" Windows Explorer.